# 440Hz triangular wave generator makes slow non-triangles

Tags: operational-amplifier, waveform

I'm attempting to generate a 440Hz triangular wave with the following circuit powered by a +5 V DC supply:

[image: Attempted 440Hz generator]

The circuit uses an NE532 low-power dual op-amp to build a square wave generator (left-hand IC) followed by an integrator (right-hand IC).

My understanding of this is that the 36 kΩ and 10 nF RC on the left-hand side give a frequency of $$f=\frac{1}{2πRC} \approx 442\text{ Hz}$$

The 10 kΩ voltage divider by the left-hand op-amp sets a reference voltage of 2.5 V. The result is a (I think) decent square wave, though not at the expected frequency:

[image: Square wave from op-amp]

The right-hand side is an integrator with gain $$\frac{1}{RC} = \frac{1}{100\text{ k}\Omega \times 10\text{nF}} = 1000$$ and the 10 kΩ resistor to ground serving (I think) as a pull-down resistor.

However, when I put all this together, what I get out is not a triangle wave!

[image: NOT a triangle wave]

This leads to two questions:

1. Why am I not getting a triangle?
2. Why is my frequency 103 Hz instead of 442 Hz?

Comment: You're asking the integrator to produce negative output voltage... Once you won't, it will work :)

Comment: That circuit will never work. Where did you stumble across it? With no overall negative feedback, the non-ideal integrator will hit hard against the power rails because there is nothing that controls the DC output level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add two 10k resistors, one from each of the op amps' non-inverting inputs to the positive supply rail.

Add a 1M resistor across the integrator's feedback capacitor.

Adjust square wave generator's RC values to set frequency.

Once the frequency is set, adjust integrator's RC values to set amplitude.

Alternatively use this circuit.....

[image: Triangle wave generator]

Adjust R3 and/or C2 to set frequency. Adjust R1 to set amplitude.

Adjust R7 to put mid-point voltage between R7 & R4 mid-way between op amps' saturation levels in order to get best waveform symmetry.

Answer (score 5):

Your opamps are not biased correctly with a positive, 0V and negative supply.

[image: triangle]

Answer (score 3):

You are lucky (or maybe unlucky) it oscillates at all.

Here is one way to make such an oscillator with the part you  have (NE552 and LM358 are very similar parts):

[image]

The 100K/100K dividers and the 100K/51K switched divider bias the op-amp and comparator op-amp into appropriate regions of operation with a single 5V supply. With a bipolar supply things are a bit simpler.

Rather than attempting to integrate the output of a square wave, this oscillator drives an integrator back and forth based on the voltage at the output (with hysteresis) so there is no problem with the integrator saturating.

Answer (score 0):

The NE532 (or any opamp) is not the best part to use for the oscillator portion -- you really need a comparator because the opamp's internal loop compensation slows down its output. In addition, the output of the NE532 doesn't swing from 0 to VCC, so there are some errors in the frequency from an ideal calculation.

The reason your integrator doesn't work is that it doesn't see a negative input -- its input is always + (or nearly 0).

The 10k on its '+' input is probably used to minimize input offsets, but that is not critical here. If you biased that input at ½ the square wave amplitude (approx VCC/2 -- so just add another 10k to VCC), then the integrator would have a chance at working.

However you will then run into another problem -- there is nothing stop the integrator 'creeping' upwards in successive cycles (from the input not being 50 % duty cycle, or not full amplitude, or many other reasons). You need a circuit to somehow reset it periodically. A large R across the C would work (say 1 MΩ), but this will also slightly distort your triangle wave.